# Patched function return value not being used with pytest

Tags: python, pytest, monkeypatching, python-unittest.mock

I have a test file where I'm mocking a function to return a boolean value. For example, `file1.py` is in a directory called `service`.

**file1.py**

```
def is_development():
    return is_not_other_env() or is_not_other_other_env()

APP_ENVIRONMENT = 'development' is is_development() else 'production'
```

And then the test file is to test that the variable `APP_ENVIRONMENT` is what I expect it to be.
**test_file1.py**

```
from service import file1
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch('service.file1.is_development', return_value=False)
def test_app_environment_prod():
     assert file1.APP_ENVIRONMENT == 'production'
```

But this test fails. I thought maybe I needed to reload the import so I used `importlib` to reload the module after patching but the test still fails.

Why does the patch fail here?

When I call the function directly after patching it does return `False` as I patched it, but when accessing the variable which should run the function with the patch it fails.

Comment: Depending on how you import `is_development`, your patch string is probably wrong, see [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch).

Comment: The problem is that `is_development` is being called when you import `file1` before doing the patch.